# Как открыть ссылку в своём приложении вместо браузера

Tags: android, ios, swift, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Проект построен на Ruby on Rails, есть мобильные приложения для ios/android.

Задача: перенаправить открытие ссылки на эти приложения.

Например: на сайте с телефона кликаю ссылку профиля, а она открывается в мобильном приложении.

Что потребуется, чтобы реализовать это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо будет внести пару правок в мобильные приложения, и загрузить пару файлов на сайт.

у iOS такой механизм называется universal links https://habr.com/ru/post/423315/

На Android это app links ( >= Android 6), или deep links 
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links
[https://blog.branch.io/ru/техническое-руководство-сс-апп-линкс/](https://blog.branch.io/ru/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%81/)